# Does some ingredient in coffee actually help the liver break down fibrosis?

Tags: liver, coffee, fatty-liver-disease

I've been reading about liver health for years and came across many [webpages](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coffee-liver-cirrhosis/drinking-more-coffee-may-undo-liver-damage-from-booze-idUSKCN0VR2JN) (Here is only one) that coffee can protect your liver against liver cirrhosis.

My understanding of cirrhosis is that it's when fibrosis overwhelms the liver so greatly that it starts forming dents, craters and holes where healthy tissue has died and shrunk.

Does this mean that some chemical in coffee can help the liver slowly retrieve and expel dead bits of liver (fibrosis)?

Comment: Olive oil?  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/18824281/  ; https://www.fattyliverfoundation.org/simplest_diet

Comment: (Extra Virgin Olive Oil). ; Hepatologist?  https://www.healio.com/hepatology/practice-management/news/online/%7B6be04123-77b6-467d-aab0-6dd2d932c44f%7D/what-is-a-hepatologist

Comment: The first study about olive oil is in rats, so you can't conclude much from that. "Not eating anything white" is a very vague statement.

Comment: Here is more complete diet information. For NAFLD but should still be helpful.  https://www.fattyliverfoundation.org/nafld_diet

Comment: The person from that page recommends some random healthy diet and claims she halted cirrhosis development. I wouldn't rely on that. Avoiding the causes of cirrhosis may help, though. I'm not even aware of any prescribed drugs that would cure cirrhosis. As said, mild to moderate cirrhosis may heal on its own if causes no longer exist.

Comment: @Jan Here is the medical advisory board for FLF, the association I linked to, so I would not think the diet is just some random healthy diet. I am not suggesting that the doctors necessarily designed the diet (perhaps they did, perhaps they reviewed it) but the Foundation seems to have some legitimacy. https://www.fattyliverfoundation.org/medical_advisory_board

Comment: The man who specifically wrote the passage on the diet is the founder of the Foundation. He says he is a cirrhosis patient. He says he follows a stricter version, which I am sure means, at a minimum, no alcohol.

Comment: When I first quickly checked the liverfoundation site, I thought, the article is written from experience of a single person. Now I see there are more people behind it. There is an "avoid" and "to eat" part of that diet. The "avoid" part is mainly what is today considered a healthy diet. The "to eat" part does not need to be so specific. If you ask me, avoiding alcohol, too much sugar, sedentary life style and obesity are the most important things. I suggest you search for prevention of fatty liver on some hospital websites. They describe the diet in a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion of the mentioned [systematic review with meta‐analysis: coffee consumption and the risk of cirrhosis (Alimentary Pharmacology & Therapeutics, 2016)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/apt.13523):

> This meta‐analysis suggests that increasing coffee consumption may
>   substantially *reduce the risk* of cirrhosis.

They say coffee may reduce the risk of cirrhosis, not that it can treat it.

The article mentions that caffeine, chlorogenic acid, melanoids and the pentacyclic diterpenes, kahweol and cafestol in coffee may be associated with health benefits.

According to [another systematic review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24102757), regular **coffee** consumption is associated with decreased risk of liver cirrhosis and according. [Yet another systematic review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27824642) concludes that coffee consumption is associated with decreased risk of nonalcoholic fatty liver disease.

In [another systematic review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27350575), **caffeine** consumption was associated with lower risk of liver cirrhosis in patients with hepatitis C.

These reviews say there is an *association* between coffee drinking and lower risk of cirrhosis. The actual *cause-effect relationship* between coffee drinking and cirrhosis has not been established, so far.

**Cirrhosis may be reversible.**

[Is cirrhosis of the liver reversible? (PubMed, 2007)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17476087)

> Accumulating evidence suggests that liver fibrosis is reversible and
>   that recovery from cirrhosis may be possible.

[Cirrhosis and its complications: Evidence based treatment (PubMed, 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4017060/)

> In the past cirrhosis was generally thought to be irreversible but
>   recent studies have shown that treatments aimed at the underlying
>   cause especially in earlier stages of the disease can improve or even
>   reverse fibrosis.

Comment: Oh my. So to date, is there no actual chemical that will actively break-down fibrosis?

Comment: Mild cirrhosis can heal on its own. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Not a doc......

Comment: Just a turn of phrase...